# How can I position controls absolutely using the Visual Studio 2010 asp.net design view?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, designer, css-position

I want to be able to move all the controls dynamically across the design view.
I know there is some command in the tab menu that allows you to achieve that.. you simply set all the items on the design view as "absolute" and then drag them to the position you want with the mouse... But where is that command in the menu toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Div tag, then add a control, select it and go 
Format > Set Position >  Absolute.

Now you can drag the control to the position you want.